# How to adjust a Div property to make it expandable according to the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making an application in which there were several divisions. In one particular division the content is going more than one line. As we know it will make the div scrollable to let us see the content .

But in this case I want that the div adjust its height in accordance with the content so that all the content can be seen in one go and no scroll should be there..... is there any way ??

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Screen1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Screen1.css">
</head>
<body BGCOLOR="#e9ecf1" ng-controller='screen1Controller'>
        <div class="main">
        <div id="header1Main">
            <div id="header1">Timeliness</div>
            <div id="header2">

            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
           <div class="opporMain">
                <div class="opporHeader">
                    <div class="circleIcon">I</div>
                    <div class="opporHeading">Heading is the main thing that we need now it is a very important propert and wee need it we will have the thing according to the needs .........</div>
                </div>
            <div class="lineDiv"></div>
            <div class="opporContent">
                <div class="contentStatus">one three</div>
                <div class="contentStatusDate">main thing</div>
                <div class="clearContent"></div> 
                <div class="contentMainContent">"Things have been changed according to the needs"</div>
                <div class="contentUpdateTime"><img src="images/timeline-3.png" alt="clock">&nbsp;Just Now</div>
                <div class="clearContent"></div> 
                <div class="contentUpdateBy">updated by <font color="black">ziong zhu</font></div>     
            </div>
            <div class="lineDiv"></div>
            <div class="opporComment">
                <img class="commentIcon" src="comment.png" alt="img"/>
                <div class="opporCommentContent">Comments</div>            
                <div class="opporCommentDetails">3 Comments</div>
            </div>
         </div>


            <div class="clearOppr"></div>


            </div>



      </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/application.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*ROBOTO SLAB*/


@font-face {
     font-family: 'RobotoSlab-bold';
     src:url('fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
     font-family: 'RobotoSlab-light';
     src:url('fonts/RobotoSlab-Light.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoSlab-regular';
    src:url('fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoSlab-thin';
    src:url('fonts/RobotoSlab-Thin.woff') format('woff');
}



/*ROBOTO*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-regular';
     src:url('fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-bold';
    src:url('fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-thin';
    src:url('fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-light';
    src:url('fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto-medium';
    src:url('fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}


    body 
    {   
    margin:0px; 
    }
#header1Main
{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  overflow:auto;
}
#header1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Roboto-regular;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#4f4f51;
    height: 36px;
    width:70%;
    margin-left: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header2 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20%;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 36px;

}
.img
{
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
}
.opporMain {

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(194, 194, 194, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(194, 194, 194, 0.4);
box-shadow:         0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(194, 194, 194, 0.4);

    /*-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(194,194,194,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(194,194,194,0.4);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(194,194,194,0.4);*/
margin-left:12px;
    margin-right:12px;
}
.opporHeader {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    display:block;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto;

    min-height:40px;

}
.clear {
    clear:both;
    height:12px;
}
.clearOppr {
    clear:both;
    height:10px;
}
.circleIcon {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top:6px;
    -wsebkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background-color:#ffb400;
    margin-left: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Roboto-Light;
    font-size:18px; 
    color:White;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.opporHeading {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto-bold;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    column-rule: #000;231f20;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
hr {
    clear:both;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.lineDiv {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;


}
.opporContent {

    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto;

    padding-bottom:12px;    

}
.opporComment
{
    height:30px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto;

}
.contentStatus
{

    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    font-family:RobotoSlab-Regular;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#4554a5;
    margin-top:10px;   
    margin-left:8px;

}
.contentStatusDate
{

    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    font-family:RobotoSlab-Bold;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#4554a5;
    margin-top:10px;   
    margin-left:5px;

}
.contentMainContent
{
    font-family:'RobotoSlab-Light';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:8px;    
    margin-left:8px;
}
.clearContent
{
    clear:both;    
}
.contentUpdateTime
{

    float:right;
    font-family:Roboto-Light;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:10px;    
    color:#b1b3b6;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:10px;

}
.contentUpdateBy
{
    float:right;
    font-family:Roboto-Light;
    font-size:12px;    
    font-weight:300;
    color:#b1b3b6;
    margin-top:4px;
    margin-right:10px;

}    

.opporCommentContent
{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    font-family: Roboto-Medium;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:6px;
    color:#4f4f51;
}
.commentIcon
{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:8px;
}
.opporCommentDetails
{
    float:right;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-family: Roboto-Light;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#b1b3b6;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvaibhav/4ou13gts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the CSS of `.circleIcon` and `.opporHeading` :

```
.circleIcon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin-top:6px;
    -wsebkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    background-color:#ffb400;
    margin-left: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Roboto-Light;
    font-size:18px; 
    color:White;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.opporHeading {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Roboto-bold;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    column-rule: #000;231f20;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 45px;
}
```

JSFiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ou13gts/3/)